# How Do I Make A Bool Value Change In C++?

Tags: boolean

So I've been trying to figure out the bool function for a while now.
I'm trying to make it so after a specific value is entered, the bool will become true or false.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a;
bool dead;

void Life() {
    if (dead == true) {
        cout << "You ded.";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You not ded.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 10)
    {
        bool dead = true;
    }
    Life();
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I currently have, however it isn't changing the value of the bool. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're redeclaring the variable 'dead' in main's if block. So now you have two 'bool dead', a global one, and a local one in main's if block. The statement 'bool dead = true' sets the local one, but the function 'Life()' uses the global one. Just remove the 'bool' from the latter and you will always be using the global one.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a;
bool dead;

void Life() {
    if (dead == true) {
        cout << "You ded.";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You not ded.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 10)
    {
        dead = true;
    }
    Life();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two variables called dead.
 - a global
 - a local which lifetime is the if block

You set only the local variable inside the if block. So you do not change the global variable. Remove the type inside the if block and your program may run as you intended. And don't forget to initialize your global dead variable. Depending on the OS and state your global variable may start with a true value.